# react updateing state of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So i am attempting to change a value in an array of objects on click 
my array of objects looks like

```
//Memory.json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "image" :"./images/if_Adventure_Map_2913095.png",
        "clicked" : "false"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "image":"./images/if_Armor_2913124.png",
        "clicked" : "false"
    },
]
```

and in my app.js

```
import gameobj from "./Memory.json"

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        gameobj
    }
```

I have been able to get everything to display on the page but have been unable to get the click handler to change the value of clicked in the object 
Here is what i have at current been going back and forth with a bunch of things hence all the comment out =(

```
clickHandler = event => {
// let clicked = event.target.clicked ;
// const id = event.target.alt
const target = gameobj[id].clicked

// console.log(id)
// console.log(target)
// clicked = true;
// this.setState({
//   [id]:clicked

// });

this.setState({ clicked: "true"



  })

}
```

Comment: And where is the click Handler in the above code ?

Comment: You are missing most of the code related to your problem.

Comment: been trying a bunch of different things updated post with the current state of my click handler. been unable to get something to work correctly gotten it to set a different state with an ID of the obj to true but not the value in the array

Comment: You didn't post enough code, but by guessing you should create a method to handle the click event that passes the id of the object, and then use that to get the object you want to manipulate, and then finally set the state. ie, `onClick={ () => this.handleClick(this.props.id) }`, and then do the state manipulating in the `handleClick(id)` method.